# fatal: Not a git repository: when adding files to git repo

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up git repository for my project.
I got it from SVN, copied it into new folder, did

```
git init
```

And when I try doing

```
git add .
```

I get following error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: MyApp-iOS/Frameworks/AFNetworking.git/../../../.git/modules/MyApp-iOS/Frameworks/AFNetworking.git
```

When I use git status it shows following:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
    .DS_Store
    MyApp-iOS/
    MonoApp-Gen/
    README

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

I got the project from other people, they use framework.git for their framework folders names for some reason.
How can I fix my project and make it work with git?

Comment: @AD7six How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by this error message:

> fatal: Not a git repository: .git/modules/MyApp-iOS/Frameworks/AFNetworking.git

There are submodules, and the config for it is possibly borked.

### Cleanup and start again

Assuming you are not interested in any existing git history, you can delete it and go from there e.g.:

```
find . -name ".git" -exec rm -rf {} \;
git init
git status
git add ...
git commit -v
etc.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what add ... does as it didn't work for me. I replaced with add . and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

You can set up an empty repository for them by running git init with the --bare option, which initializes the repository without a working directory:

```
cd /opt/git
mkdir project.git
cd project.git
git --bare init
```

Then you can use the commands pretty on local computer much as is:

```
cd myproject
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git remote add origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git
git push origin master
```

[See more.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)

Comment: It still fails on git add . part.
I don't need to have or setup server, I just want to have local git repository. I have files, I can't add them to repository as it shows error.

Comment: I tried my svn repository and everything worked perfectly. Sorry for the wrong answer...